# What does subcopula mean?

Tags: probability, special-functions

In copula concept, what does "subcopula" exactly mean? Does it mean a subset of copula? Would you please explain a little bit in details?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This should help: https://books.google.com/books?id=EqbzBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA8&lpg=PA8&dq=subcopula&source=bl&ots=Ev_Xpg8Nko&sig=-rN-HpJi99qEIj3JfhUeJsxRVoA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_hVbVeWsNM6wsASyiYCICw&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=subcopula&f=false